# Alternatives to U-Net for biomedical image segmentation

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation, medical

Soon I will be working on biomedical image semgentation (microscopy images). There will be a small amount of data (a few dozens at best). My question is really straightforward: is there a neural network, that can compete with U-Net in this case? I've spent last few hours searching through scientific articles that are dealing with this topic, but haven't found a clear answer and I would like to know what other possibilities are. The best answers I found are that I could consider using ResU-Net/R2U-Net, SegNet.

Any ideas (with evidence, not necessarily)?

Comment: This question is better suited for communities such as Data science StackExchange or Artificial Intelligence StackExchange considering that it does not involve programming issues. Also, just to understand your question better: are you looking for an architecture to train from scratch or for pre-trained model to use for transfer learning?

Comment: Oh my, you're totally right, I should have thought of it myself.. My fault.. Just an architecture, the task will be too specific I believe to perform transfer learning  :)